# How to make Android tabs scale properly with phones/tablets

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-tabs

I have a scaling problem with my sherlock-tabs in my tablet-layout as can be seen in this picture:

[image]

For some reason the tablet-layout does not scale properly as it does in the phone-layout. The width of the tabs is not wide enough in the tablet-layout. If it is not possible to make the width larger of the tabs in the tablet-layout, I would like do to so. If not, I would atleast wish to move them to the left.

The issue can be seen to the left of the white search-tab (the selected tab). I would like to left_align the tabs so it won't leave an empty space.

How do i accomplish this without making my phone-layout look like crap? Any ideas what I should do with my code?

**Tabs.java** (implementing tabs in java)

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tab_host);

        settings = Injecter.settings(this);
        setOnCreatePreferences();

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(false);

        actionBar.setTitle(R.string.LabelTitleAbout);

        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().
                 //setText(R.string.LabelSearchTabTitle).
            setIcon(R.drawable.ic_tab_search).
                //setTabListener(this));
                setTabListener(new TabListener<LandingSearch>(this, getString(R.string.LabelSearchTabTitle), LandingSearch.class, null)));

*code continues with the rest of the tabs...*

public class TabListener<T extends Fragment> implements ActionBar.TabListener {
        private final FragmentActivity mActivity;
        private final String mTag;
        private final Class<T> mClass;
        private final Bundle mArgs;
        private Fragment mFragment;

        public TabListener(FragmentActivity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz, Bundle args) {
            mActivity = activity;
            mTag = tag;
            mClass = clz;
            mArgs = args;
            FragmentTransaction ft = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            // Check to see if we already have a fragment for this tab, probably
            // from a previously saved state.  If so, deactivate it, because our
            // initial state is that a tab isn't shown.
            mFragment = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(mTag);
            if (mFragment != null && !mFragment.isDetached()) {
                ft.detach(mFragment);
            }
            ft.commit();
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction transaction) {
            if (mFragment == null) {
                FragmentTransaction ft = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); 
                mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName(), mArgs);
            //  ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
                ft.replace(R.id.tabs_navigation_content, mFragment, mTag);
                ft.commit();
            } else {
                FragmentTransaction ft = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); 
                ft.attach(mFragment);
                ft.commit();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction transaction) {
            if (mFragment != null) {
                FragmentTransaction ft = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); 
                ft.detach(mFragment);
                ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

        }
    }
}
```

**tab_host.xml** (setting contentView for tabs from the tabs.java code. Not sure if I have missed any attribute here which makes the scaling strange for tablets?)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs_navigation_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**tab_bar_background.xml** (setting the tabBar background from the themes.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tabbar_brown"/>
  <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_bar_background_selected"/>
  <item android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tabbar_grey"/>
  <item android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_bar_background_selected_pressed"/>
</selector>
```

**tab_bar_background_selected.xml** (defines that a selected tab should have white background)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:top="-5dp" android:left="-5dp" android:right="-5dp" android:drawable="@drawable/tabbar_white" >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke android:color="@color/black" android:width="-5dp"/>

        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**themes.xml** (general settings for actionBar and tabBar)

```
<style name="Theme.ML" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
         <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/bg_math</item>
         <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/Theme.ML.Tabs</item>
         <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/Theme.ML.Tabs</item>

         <item name="actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/Theme.ML.Tabs</item>
         <item name="android:actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/Theme.ML.Tabs</item>

         <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Theme.ML.Tabs</item>
         <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Theme.ML.Tabs</item>  

    </style>

    <style name="Theme.ML.ActionBar" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
         <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/bg_math</item>
         <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/Theme.ML.Tabs</item>
         <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/Theme.ML.Tabs</item>

         <item name="actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/Theme.ML.Tabs</item>
         <item name="android:actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/Theme.ML.Tabs</item>

         <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Theme.ML.Tabs</item>
         <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Theme.ML.Tabs</item>  

         <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/Theme.ML.Text</item>
         <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/Theme.ML.Text</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.ML.Tabs" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabBar">

        <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>  
        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>  

        <item name="background">@drawable/tab_bar_background</item> 
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_bar_background</item>
    </style>
```

Regards

Comment: Can you specify the version of Android SDK you're using?

Comment: <uses-sdk
        android:maxSdkVersion="20"
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="20" />

Comment: Note that action bar tabs are deprecated in the "L" Developer Preview and should remain deprecated in the next shipping release of Android. You may wish to consider alternative tab solutions, such as a `ViewPager` with a tabbed indicator.